# Get the WNDPROC for windows handle

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi

Exist any  Windows api function to retrieve the `WNDPROC` for a Windows Handle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585.aspx)(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC).

Caution: GetWindowLongPtr is actually `#define`d to GetWindowLong for 32-bit systems, so in order to import it in Delphi you might need to use GetWindowLong instead. As well, GetWindowLongPtr itself is `#define`d to either GetWindowLongPtrA or GetWindowLongPtrW (for non-unicode and unicode targets), so again you might need to choose the right name manually for Delphi if the import system there is not really smart.

---

Remember that if you are going to call the obtained window proc, you should do it using [CallWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633571.aspx). Thanks to @In silico for the hint.

---

Please note that the value which is returned is not always the real pointer to the window procedure. Sometimes it's just a kind of handle which is recognized and correctly processed by `CallWindowProc`. For example, you'll not get the real function pointer if your application is ANSI, but the window belongs to a Unicode component (or vice versa). See [this posting in *The Old New Thing*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031201-00/?p=41673) for more details.

Comment: @Salvador: If you intend to call the returned `WNDPROC`, you must use [`CallWindowProc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633571.aspx).

Comment: recent versions of Delphi define GetWindowLongPtr and also handle the UNICODE/ANSI mapping automatically

Comment: @David: good to know, thanks! Hopefully the OP has a version of Delphi recent enough. If not, he is warned to try `GetWindowLong` as well (or better use some conditional compilation).