# How do I test if my custom callback is set as the current procedure for a given window?

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, function-pointers, unmanaged, kiosk-mode

We have a kiosk mode application for Windows Mobile 5 that was going strong for a year at least in production. It uses window subclassing through the [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) windows API function to override the behavior of the taskbar to prevent users from ever leaving our application or other explicitly allowed applications.

My callback overrides the handling of a few window messages and calls the default handler for other messages. This is done by storing the previous function pointer returned by `SetWindowLong`, and using it inside of the new function by calling `CallWindowProc` on it.

Then we had to update the application to be compatible with Windows Mobile 6.5.3, and started having a bunch of problems. I followed [this article](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/11/18/mobile-development-disable-windows-mobile-6-5-start-and-close-button/) to disable the bottom menu buttons which are new on 6.5. On a single application, it works fine and the menu respects my callback. As soon as the user opens up another application through ours, that window seems to be recreated, and I had to devise a mechanism to detect foreground window changes and then "resubclass" the window again.

In my code, I don't have control of when exactly this window is recreated, so my first attempt was to use the `GetWindowLong` function to obtain the current callback address and test it against my own function address. I learned the hard way that I can't just compare the values like that, since [it does not always return the function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4341321/1946412).

Because I'm not able to test if my method is the current handler that way, I end up sometimes setting my method as the handler, and the previous handler is also my own method (in this case, the window was not recreated and thus already had my method set). This results in an infinite loop, since my callback ends up calling itself indefinitely.

How can I know if my custom function is the one being used by a certain window, so that I can avoid this infinite recursion?

Comment: The notion of a window being "recreated" is pretty nonsensical.  After WM_NCDESTROY is it is a dead parrot and you no longer have any use for the window handle.

Comment: Use a custom window property to tag the windows you have already subclassed. Even better: Use SetWindowSubclass, which handles all this for you.

Comment: @HansPassant It wouldn't make any sense to use the same handle indeed. What I do is use `FindWindow` with a class to find the new handle and then subclass that new window that way. Does that make more sense? The window I'm trying to subclass is the bottom menu bar on the Windows Mobile 6.5 system, if that helps any.

Comment: @RaymondChen I updated the question to reflect that I need to do this on Windows Mobile, which does not have the `SetWindowSubclass` function. Sorry for the confusion. Could you elaborate that point about setting a tag on the window itself? I've never done that and it seems less hackish than creating a custom message and response to test my callback.

Comment: You can use [SetProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922089.aspx) to set the tag on the window. `SetProp(hwnd, TEXT("SubclassedByKilroy"), (HANDLE)1)`. You can then use `GetProp(hwnd, TEXT("SubclassedByKilroy"))` to query for the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `SetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)` to subclass a window.  Use [`SetWindowSubClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead (like Raymond Chen said):

[Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx)

[Safer subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx)

Amongst providing safer subclassing semantics (such as allowing multiple subclasses at a time), it also allows you to associate user-defined data with each subclass.  So you could use [`GetWindowSubclass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776430.aspx) to check if you have already subclassed the window or not.

Or, you could simply keep track of whether or not you have already subclassed the window.  A simple boolean variable will suffice.  Once your subclass is in place, you MUST remove the subclass before the window is fully destroyed.  So, for instance, when the subclass receives the `WM_NCDESTROY` message, you can remove the subclass and clear your boolean at the same time, and then the next time you see the window again your boolean will tell you that you need to subclass the window.

Comment: I didn't mention I was doing this in Windows Mobile 6.5 because I naively thought there would be no difference... Turns out `SetWindowSubClass` is not available there, so I can't use your solution :(. Will update the question to reflect that, and would appreciate if you could update the answer also. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Send the custom message to window. Handle this message in your custom function to return some value that will indicate that it was your custom handler.. and so on.

```
if(SendMessage(hwnd, mymsg, 0, 0) != myvalue)
    ;// It's not your handler
```

Comment: I think I'll have to go with this. I started coding it yesterday right after I posted the question, as it seemed to be the only way to achieve it given my constraints.